# Optimized db2 query with total count and pagination

Tags: optimization, pagination, db2, query-optimization, rowcount

I have complex query which I am simplifying for greater understanding.

**Query:** The query is having group by, order by, where clause and multiple joins with other tables.

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM CUSTOMERS ;
```

**Requirement:** **NEED OPTIMIZED APPROACH**, Get the total count of records of a BIG query along with pagination.

**My approach 1:**  Execute two queries to find count first and then paginated rows
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FROM CUSTOMERS ;

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROWNUMER FROM (
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMERCID) AS ROWNUMER FROM CUSTOMERS 
)WHERE ROWNUMER BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

**My approach 2:** Find total count as well as get the required paginated rows in a single query.

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROWNUMER, COUNTROWS FROM (
          SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMERCID) AS ROWNUMER
          FROM CUSTOMERS 
) AS CUST, (SELECT COUNT(1) AS COUNTROWS   FROM CUSTOMERS ) AS COUNTNUM
WHERE ROWNUMER BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

**My approach 3:**  Create a VIEW of second approach.

Please suggest which approach I should opt? As per my research, 3rd approach will be more optimized compared to other approach as DATABSE VIEWS are more optimized.

Comment: Side note: `BETWEEN` is _inclusive_ on both ends (`>=` and `<=`), which means `BETWEEN 10 AND 20` nets you **11** results (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20).  You also can't just add the span-distance from start to end (10) to get the next start page - the first entry on a given page is the same as the last on the previous page (you'd have to add one more... 21, 32, 43...).   So, split the comparison and use an exclusive upper bound (`<`), which will solve this.  Oh, please upgrade to using explicit joins (the `JOIN` clause) - implicit joins have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing about a view that automatically makes it "more optimized" than the query contained within it. The query optimizer decomposes the original SQL and often rewrites it into a much different-looking statement before execution.

After performing `RUNSTATS` to ensure your tables and indexes have accurate statistics, DB2's built-in EXPLAIN tools such as the `db2expln` utility, the Design Advisor (`db2advis`), and the Visual Explain tool in IBM Data Studio offer the best chance at understanding exactly why a particular query option is better or worse than another.

Comment: Using material view or materialized query table in db2 will surely help to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Best performance for pagination is when the least number columns are doing the work (pagination) and then join the results by the key columns to get more data.  Two columns control pagination customercid and rownumber one is the primary key already indexed because customercid I'm assuming is unique.  customercid is also in the row_number() function so this is the most efficient pagination.

```
create view dancustomercid as 
SELECT CustomerCID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMERCID) AS ROWNUMER FROM CUSTOMERS
```

Then join on the output from the view notice there is no order by to slow things down just a join on key fields customercid

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROWNUMBER from dancustomercid a join CUSTOMERCID AS b on
a.customercid = b.customercid where a.ROWNUMER  
BETWEEN 11 AND 20;
```